# How to make setState in React synchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a calculator app in React. I am facing some weird issues. 
The problem lies in the `computeResult()` function. The code logic is to push the numbers and operators into the `calculationArray`, and when the user clicks the `=` button the `computeResult()` function is invoked.

The first problem I faced was when the user clicks `=` button, the last number keyed in or latest `expression` after the last operator, needed to be pushed into the `calculationArray`. I found that setState is async, so I made a new array `tempcalculationArray` by concatenating the last 'expression' with `calculationArray`. Then using a `for` loop the total was calculated. The `total` was getting logged to the console from inside of the `for` loop.

Then the second problem occurred, the `console.log` after the `for` loop was not working.

The third issue is the `setState` after the `for` loop is also not working.

This is the code:

```js
const Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      expression: "",
      calculationArray: [],      
      answer: 0, 
      waitingForOperator: true,
    };
  },
  
  inputDigit(val) {
    const { expression, valueHolder, operator, waitingForOperator } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      expression: expression === "0" ? String(val) : expression + String(val),
      waitingForOperator:true
    });
  },
  
  inputDot() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    if (expression.indexOf(".") == -1) {
      this.setState({
        expression: expression=="" ? "0." :expression + "."
      });
    }
  },
  
  inputSign() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    if (expression.charAt(0) == "-") {
      this.setState({
        expression: expression.substr(1)
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        expression: "-" + expression
      });
    }
  },
  
  clearAll() {
    const { expression , calculationArray, answer} = this.state;
    this.setState({
      expression: "",
      calculationArray: [],
      answer: 0
    });
  },
  
  backSpace() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      expression: expression.substr(0, expression.length - 1)
    });
  },
  percent() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      expression: String(Number(expression)/100)
    });
  },
  
  inputOperator(oper) {
    const { expression, calculationArray, waitingForOperator} = this.state;
    if(waitingForOperator){
      this.setState({      
        calculationArray: calculationArray.concat(expression).concat(oper),
        expression:"",
        waitingForOperator:false

      });
    }
    
  },

  computeResult() {
    const { expression, calculationArray, waitingForOperator, answer} = this.state;
    var arithmetic = {
        '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
        '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
        '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
        '/': function (x, y) { return x / y },
    };    
    var total = Number(calculationArray[0]);
    var tempcalculationArray = calculationArray.concat(expression);
    console.log(tempcalculationArray);
    for(var i=1; i<=tempcalculationArray.length; i=i+2){
      total = arithmetic[tempcalculationArray[i]](total, Number(tempcalculationArray[i+1]));
      console.log(total);
    }
    console.log( "why I am not getting printed on console");
    this.setState({      
      calculationArray: calculationArray.concat(expression),
      waitingForOperator:false,
      answer: total
    });
    
  },
  
  render() {
    const { expression, answer, math } = this.state;
    const { updateExpression, computeResult } = this;

    return (
      <div>

        <div id="displayarea">
          <div id="equation"><p>{expression}</p></div>
          <div id="answer"><p>{answer}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="calculatorpanel">

          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.clearAll()}>AC</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.backSpace()}>←</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("/")}>÷</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("*")}>X</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(7)}>
              7
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(8)}>
              8
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(9)}>
              9
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("-")}>-</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(4)}>
              4
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(5)}>
              5
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(6)}>
              6
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("+")}>+</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(1)}>
              1
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(2)}>
              2
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(3)}>
              3
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.percent()}>%</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(0)}>
              0
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputSign()}>±</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDot()}>.</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.computeResult()}>=</button>

          </div>
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("calculator"));
```

```css
#equation { border: 1px solid #ee82ee; }
#answer { border: 1px solid #00f; }
p { height: 1em; margin: 0; padding: .5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator"></div>
```

Note: Before anyone downvote this question, Please note I have searched thoroughly through the stackflow questions and read most of them, most of the answers do not apply in my scenario. Also, This question cannot be a possible duplicate because I'm looking for a better way to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then the second problem occurred, the `console.log` after the for loop was not working.
>
> The third issue is the setState after the for loop is also not working.

I love CodePen, but its console kind of sucks. In particular, it doesn't report errors. If you open your browser's built-in JavaScript console and run your code, you'll see an error like this when you click on the `=` button:

> `Uncaught TypeError: arithmetic[tempcalculationArray[i]] is not a function`

This is the cause of both the second and third problems: When an error is thrown, your code stops.

The cause is here:

```
for(var i=1; i<=tempcalculationArray.length; i=i+2){
  total = arithmetic[tempcalculationArray[i]](total, Number(tempcalculationArray[i+1]));
  // ...
```

This `for` loop will run as long as `i` is less than **or equal to** `templcalcuationArray.length`. If `i` is equal to the length of the array, it's greater than the index of the last element in the array, and `tempcalculationArray[i]` on the next line will return `undefined`, and `undefined` is not a function.

The solution is to use the `<` operator instead of `<=`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < tempcalculationArray.length; i += 2) {
```

Here it is in a working snippet:

```js
const Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      expression: "",
      calculationArray: [],      
      answer: 0, 
      waitingForOperator: true,
    };
  },
  
  inputDigit(val) {
    const { expression, valueHolder, operator, waitingForOperator } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      expression: expression === "0" ? String(val) : expression + String(val),
      waitingForOperator:true
    });
  },
  
  inputDot() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    if (expression.indexOf(".") == -1) {
      this.setState({
        expression: expression=="" ? "0." :expression + "."
      });
    }
  },
  
  inputSign() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    if (expression.charAt(0) == "-") {
      this.setState({
        expression: expression.substr(1)
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        expression: "-" + expression
      });
    }
  },
  
  clearAll() {
    const { expression , calculationArray, answer} = this.state;
    this.setState({
      expression: "",
      calculationArray: [],
      answer: 0
    });
  },
  
  backSpace() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      expression: expression.substr(0, expression.length - 1)
    });
  },
  percent() {
    const { expression } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      expression: String(Number(expression)/100)
    });
  },
  
  inputOperator(oper) {
    const { expression, calculationArray, waitingForOperator} = this.state;
    if(waitingForOperator){
      this.setState({      
        calculationArray: calculationArray.concat(expression).concat(oper),
        expression:"",
        waitingForOperator:false

      });
    }
    
  },

  computeResult() {
    const { expression, calculationArray, waitingForOperator, answer} = this.state;
    var arithmetic = {
        '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
        '-': function (x, y) { return x - y },
        '*': function (x, y) { return x * y },
        '/': function (x, y) { return x / y },
    };    
    var total = Number(calculationArray[0]);
    var tempcalculationArray = calculationArray.concat(expression);
    console.log(tempcalculationArray);
    for(var i=1; i<tempcalculationArray.length; i=i+2){
      console.log(i, tempcalculationArray[i]);
      total = arithmetic[tempcalculationArray[i]](total, Number(tempcalculationArray[i+1]));
      console.log(total);
    }
    console.log( "why I am not getting printed on console");
    this.setState({      
      calculationArray: calculationArray.concat(expression),
      waitingForOperator:false,
      answer: total
    });
    
  },
  
  render() {
    const { expression, answer, math } = this.state;
    const { updateExpression, computeResult } = this;

    return (
      <div>

        <div id="displayarea">
          <div id="equation"><p>{expression}</p></div>
          <div id="answer"><p>{answer}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="calculatorpanel">

          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.clearAll()}>AC</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.backSpace()}>←</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("/")}>÷</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("*")}>X</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(7)}>
              7
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(8)}>
              8
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(9)}>
              9
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("-")}>-</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(4)}>
              4
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(5)}>
              5
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(6)}>
              6
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputOperator("+")}>+</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(1)}>
              1
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(2)}>
              2
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(3)}>
              3
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.percent()}>%</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(0)}>
              0
            </button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputSign()}>±</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.inputDot()}>.</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.computeResult()}>=</button>

          </div>
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("calculator"));
```

```css
#equation { border: 1px solid #ee82ee; }
#answer { border: 1px solid #00f; }
p { height: 1em; margin: 0; padding: .5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator"></div>
```